# Get all entries from a table which have the searched month in a date field

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has 3 fields: `ID`, `startdate`, `stopdate`.

They have the type "date".

How can I select all entries which have the `startdate` in a given month?

For example: Show me all entries where the `startdate` is in the month "08".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblName
WHERE MONTH(startdate) = 8
```

---

Line by line break-up:

1. `SELECT *` => selects all columns
2. `FROM tblName` => the rows should be fetched from `tblName` table.
3. `WHERE MONTH(startdate) = 8` => the `startdate` is in the month **08**.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, it's the obvious

```
select * from mytable where month(date_field) = 8
```