# Can I give an intermediate string to fetch from mysql table which values has that string in middle?

Tags: php, mysql, database

For Example :-

I have saved date in my table in the format of **ddmmyyyy**

Now I need to fetch rows of month **03**

So my query can be

```
Select * 
from orders 
where date = "%03%"
```

But it will bring values of date 03 and year 2003 too.

Is there anyway to fetch the values where the **03** is in the position of **3rd** and **4th** in the string?

Comment: if you have stored in date in a "date" field type, then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639179/mysql-get-all-entries-from-a-table-which-has-the-searched-month-in-a-date-type

Comment: You better store dates as `DATE` type. That would allow you to use a lot of [built in functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) like `MONTH()`. With your format you can't even easily sort the result.

Comment: Oh well thanks! I here gave just an example for better understanding. And that date type is new info for me. thanks for that. but still my question is "Is there anyway to fetch the strings which has some intermediate strings in exact position?

Comment: I got the answer that i want, from below answers. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it. You can use [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE SUBSTRING(`date`, 3, 2) = "03"
```

Using `LIKE "__03____"` as shown in the other answers should also work.

My favorite option would be to

## ***[`STORE YOUR DATES IN A DATE COLUMN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)***

so you can just [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639228/2734189):

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 3
```

---

FYI:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD COLUMN order_date DATE;
UPDATE orders SET order_date = str_to_date(`date`,'%d%m%Y');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It gonna help me in my next question too i guess. If possible answer that question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155714/how-to-fetch-rows-between-two-values-in-a-column-mysql

Comment: @Karthik have you converted your column to a date type? I included some code at the end of my answer that should do that.

Comment: I did @Don't Panic. But i did manually. Thank you so much btw!

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the value just by the position of the characters, use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `date` LIKE "__03____"
```

[From the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

> _ matches exactly one character.

Whereas

> % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.

The latter would be invalid in your case - as you will have the issue you already experienced in that it will match anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, "%" matches zero or more characters, while "_" matches exactly *one* character. Thus, you would want to match against "__03%" or "__03____".

Furthermore, you must use "LIKE" instead of "=" in order to handle wildcards (and use a backslash to escape any literal instances of said characters).

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html for more information

Comment: Thanks for the instant answer. It helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from orders where month(str_to_date(date,'%d%m%Y')) = 03
```

Answer (score -1):

date is stored in "Y-m-d" format in MySQL, if you have stored your date as a text then you can try

```
 SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `date` LIKE "__03____";;
```

Comment: `"%03%"` does not work in t his case, as it still matches `03xxxxxx` and `xxxxxx03`.