# How to fetch rows between two values in a column MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have saved dates in my MySQL table as VARCHAR format.

I want to fetch rows between two dates.

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date BETWEEN '01-02-2017' AND '28-02-2017'
```

This one didn't work. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Dates should be stored as `date` or `datetime` format

Comment: I have plenty of rows already saved. If i change the format now, Will it affect all the values in that column?

Comment: They are not dates - they are strings.  Storing dates as varchars has prevented you from doing anything logic-wise with dates.

Comment: Make a table copy, change and see.

Comment: It made all that values as 0000-00-00 :p No more ways to do ah?

Comment: @u_mulder If i change format now, in which format i should save dates?

Answer (score 0):

- Try This..
- and store date data type as a date

select Date from emp_tbl where eid = 1 and Date >= '2016/03/31' and Date <= '2017/03/31'

Comment: select * from orders_tbl where eid = 1 and Date >= '2017/02/01' and Date <= '2017/02/28'

Comment: Thanks bro! I was expecting for a way without changing the format. Coz i have stored many rows laready and have made to view it in many php pages. Thats why asked.